# MySQL select issue ( unique )

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields :

date / source / destination

The same source can go to the same destination but at different time.
Multiple sources can go to same destination, etc.

I am looking to extract all destinations that have unique sources.

Comment: Please provide more information or i fear it will get closed

Comment: You need to provide some more information. What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit hard to try to help with so little info, but maybe this could work?

```
SELECT Destination 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY Destination
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Source) = 1
```

Comment: +1 for @Filipe who pointed out my inital error